# Query Facebook Opengraph next page parameters

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am unable to implement pagination with Facebook OpenGraph.  I have exhausted every option I have found.

My hope is to query for 500 listens repeatedly until there are none left.  However, I am only able to receive a response from my first query.  Below is my current code, but I have tried setting the parameters to different amounts rather than having the fields from the [page][next] dictate them

```
$q_param['limit'] = 500;
$next_exists = true;

    while($next_exists){
        $music = $facebook->api('/me/music.listens','GET', $q_param);
        $music_data = array_merge($music_data, $music['data']);

        if($music["paging"]["next"]==null || $music["paging"]["next"]=="")
            $next_exists = false;

        else{
            $url = $music["paging"]["next"];
            parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $array);

            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                $q_param[$key]=$value; 
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

a - Can you please share what do you get after first call?

b - Also, possible if you can share the whole file?

I think your script is timing out. Try adding following on top of your file:

set_time_limit(0);

Can you check apache log files?

sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log